# android microusb 有線接続での、ゲームコントローラー制御について

Tags: android, kotlin, usb

androidにてkotlinを使って趣味でappを作ったりしています。
android micro usb 有線接続で、物理ボタンやゲームコントローラーなどを接続し、その特定のボタンを押したら、それを検知してなにかのアクションを起こしたいです。
できれば、二股コード等にも対応できるようにしたいです。
で、現在調べているのですが、あまりわからず、
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice
ここに書かれていることに関連するものなのですか？
加えて、全く関係ないものなだとしたら、用語や、ドキュメント等を教えていただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: 見る所はこちらでは？ [コントローラの操作を処理する | Android デベロッパー>ドキュメント>ガイド](https://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers/controller-input?hl=ja)

Comment: ありがとうございます！！！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Androidでゲームコントローラに関連する記事はこちらでしょう。

[ゲーム コントローラをサポートする | Android デベロッパー>ドキュメント>ガイド](https://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers?hl=ja)

> プレーヤーが自分のお気に入りのゲーム コントローラを使用できるようにすることで、ゲームのユーザー エクスペリエンスを大幅に高めることができます。Android フレームワークには、ゲーム コントローラからのユーザー入力を検出して処理するための API が用意されています。
>
> このクラスでは、各種の Android API レベル（API レベル 9 以上）においてゲーム コントローラを使ってゲームを同じように操作できるようにする方法と、アプリで複数のコントローラを同時にサポートすることによってプレーヤーのゲーミング エクスペリエンスを高める方法について説明します。

[コントローラの操作を処理する | Android デベロッパー>ドキュメント>ガイド](https://developer.android.com/training/game-controllers/controller-input?hl=ja)

> Android はシステムレベルで、ゲーム コントローラからの入力イベントコードを Android のキーコードおよび軸の値としてレポートします。ゲームでこれらのコードと値を受け取って、特定のゲーム内アクションに変換することができます。
>
> プレーヤーがゲーム コントローラと Android デバイスを物理的に接続するか、無線でペア設定すると、システムがコントローラを入力デバイスとして自動検出し、入力イベントのレポートを開始します。アクティブな[Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity?hl=ja)またはフォーカスされている[View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View?hl=ja)に以下のコールバック メソッドを実装することにより、ゲームでこれらの入力イベントを受け取ることができます（Activity または View（両方ではない）のコールバックを実装する必要があります）。

以下省略。